# How to use multiple scopes with Blazor CSS isolation?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a problem with Blazor CSS isolation. What I'm trying is to work with a custom `Flex.razor` component, which is aimed at making work with CSS `flex` a bit nicer.

Here is my `Flex.razor` class:

```
<div class=@_combinedClass
     style=@Style
     onclick=@OnClick
     title=@Title
     id=@Id>
     @ChildContent
</div>
```

There's some code-behind involved, which receives all the flex options (e.g. `flex-wrap`, `justify-content` as enum parameter.

I should also note that I'm using `CSS Isolation`. The Flex.razor has a Flex.razor.less class which represents all the flex options.

Okay, so this works very nice. However, I'm facing a problem once I'm trying to use this. For example, I have a component called `Images.razor`. This component goes like the following:

```
<Flex Class="ImagePageGrid">
<Flex Class="ImageList"
      Direction="FlexDirection.Column">
    @foreach (var imageInfo in _uploadedImages)
    {
        <ImageEntry ImageInfo=@imageInfo />
    }
...
```

`ImagePageGrid` is a style tied to the `Images.razor.less` isolation.

The problem at hand is the following. It seems like when I'm using the `Flex.razor` component, Blazor will use the Flex-scope (I verified this with the resulting css bundle and the chrome dev-tools), and ignores all the custom classes for the actual `Images.razor` component.

Is there a way to make both components play nicely? I'm trying around a lot with the `::deep` modifier, but to no success yet

Comment: `ImagePageGrid` stands in the `Images` scope, not in the `Flex` scope?

Comment: @Ergis Correct. But I'd like to have the Flex use it without much hassle. I've found a workaround now, but I'd still like to get to know easier ways

Comment: You may need to wrap it in a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it seems like I found a workaround:

It seems like I have to wrap my component like this

```
<div class="Container">
    <Flex Class="ImagePageGrid">
    <Flex Class="ImageList"
        Direction="FlexDirection.Column">
        @foreach (var imageInfo in _uploadedImages)
        {
             <ImageEntry ImageInfo=@imageInfo />
        }
    ...
```

and just wrap all my css within my Images.razor.less file like this

```
.Container {
    :deep .ImagePageGrid {
        ....
    }
}
```

The ::deep is important, as it propagates style to the child

Then Blazor will properly apply styles, as hinted in the note in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#child-component-support. It feels clunky, but it seems like this is the way

Comment: This css you added stands in the `Images.razor.css`, right?

Comment: @Ergis Yes, sorry, I'll add this in the answer

Comment: I've been into Blazor for 2 weeks now. Didn't know about CSS isolation yet. Thnx for introducing it to me, lol :)

Comment: @Ergis It's a new feature which came in with Net5.0 so it hasn't been around for long, I only recently learned about it as well

Comment: Oh, nice. Loving Blazor and its evolution